# replace values on a list with integers, float and strings without changing the list structure

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have this code

```
a=[0,['hello','charles', 'hey', 'steve', 'hey', 0.0, 1.5, 23]]  
for row in a:
   for ix, char in enumerate(row):
       if 'hello' in char:
           row[ix] = 'Good Morning'
```

But this doesn't work, because I have integer, float and string at the same list.
I need to change hello with Good Morning and saving the data structure and attributes types because I will do some arithmetic calculation with that data later. 
Thanks!

Comment: check the type of `char` before checking `if 'hello' in char`

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is replace "Hello" with "good morning", you can just do this:

```
a = [[0], ['hello','charles', 'hey', 'steve', 'hey', 0.0, 1.5, 23]]  
for row in a:
    for index, item in enumerate(row):
        if item == "hello":
            row[index] = "Good morning"
```

If you really want to replace any string containing "hello", I would wrap the whole thing in a try except block:

```
a = [[0], ['hello','charles', 'hey', 'steve', 'hey', 0.0, 1.5, 23]]  
for row in a:
    for index, item in enumerate(row):
        try:
            if "hello" in item:
                row[index] = "Good morning"
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

By the way, "char" is a terrible variable name. Your rows don't contain length one strings, so they aren't chars.

The first row should really be a list containing a single integer. If you really don't want to do that for some reason, you'll have to wrap the whole thing up in another try/except block:

```
a = [0, ['hello','charles', 'hey', 'steve', 'hey', 0.0, 1.5, 23]]  
for row in a:
    try:
        for index, item in enumerate(row):
            if item == "hello":
                row[index] = "Good morning"
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried the code and it gave me a message error. int object is not iterable.

Comment: Oh. I thought your first thing was a list containing an integer. Could I ask why it isn't?

Comment: I have a free schema database, and that is a list from the database.

Comment: You might also get an error in trying to enumerate the first row (because it's just a number and not a list). It would be easier if you were able to start with a=[[0],['hello', etc]] EDIT. I see this point was just raised. You might need to put a try-except on the row enumeration, because it will fail for the first row.

Comment: That's really strange. Normally matrices are represented as lists of lists. But I've added in a version that avoids the exception. (You could do LBYL if you wanted isntead of catching the exception. hasattr(row, "`__iter__`") would do the trick.

Comment: I changes my list to just one list like a = ['hello','charles', 'hey', 'steve', 'hey', 0.0, 1.5, 23], but it still not working with the same error message

Comment: I got false false false 3 times.

Comment: Strange. I get exactly what I would expect. Did you run the last example? (None of the examples should merge it into one list, however) What do you mean by "I got false false false three times"? Nothing is being returned, so I don't know what you mean.